# Issue with a matrices equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

If i have a matrix $W \in \Re^{mxc} $ and a matrix with orthonormal columns $E \in \Re^{nxm}$ and another matrix $B \in \Re^{mxm}$ which is symmetric and positive and where $B=EE^T$ then how could we establish the following equivalence :
$(E^TW)^T (E^TW)^T = W^TBW$ ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not $(E^TW)^T (E^TW) = W^TBW$?

Comment: Because then you get $(E^TW)^T(E^TW) = W^T (E^T)^T E^T W = W^T EE^T W = W^TBW$